# python sl4a createDialogInput not working correctly with numbers

Tags: android, python, user-interface, input, sl4a

I made a little script to run in sl4a and I need to get a negative number.
Using dialogCreateInput like follow, the keyboard in number mode is show, but the signals not work.

Nor the buttons OK and Cancel are not show!

How to make a negative number be entered via soft keyboard in number mode ?

This doesn't works:

```
app.dialogCreateInput('Valor', "Informe o valor da operação.", "-", "number" ).result
app.dialogShow()
v1=app.dialogGetResponse().result
```

This works

```
v1 = app.dialogGetInput('Valor', "Informe o valor da operação", "-" ).result
valor = v1
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw a link in the doc [dialogCreateInput](https://www.mithril.com.au/android/doc/UiFacade.html#dialogCreateInput) that points to the possible values of inputType [TextView_inputType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_inputType). Did you try the value "numberSigned" ?